# how can i get value from combo box and show it to textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

how can show value of selected item in combobox in textblock ?

i use this code to get value .

```
  combobox20.ItemsSource = database.Mavads.ToList();
            combobox20.DisplayMemberPath = "MavadName";
            combobox20.SelectedValuePath = "MavadFe";
```

I try to get it with this code

```
txt_f1.Text = combobox1.SelectedValuePath ;
```

but show me 
"MavadFe"

i use event "IsMouseCapturedChanged"

Comment: what do you need actually? do you wish to add all checked values to textbox?

Comment: no, i want to get value and show it in textbox

Comment: which you clicked?

Comment: @EmadShojaeenasab try this `txt_f1.Text = combobox1.Text;` on `MouseLeftButtonUp` Event of `ComboBox`

Answer (score 2):

The `SelectedValuePath` sets the field used to represent whatever item you've selected, but to get the actual selected value you need `SelectedValue`. It's an object, so assuming the "MavadFe" field is a string, just convert it.

```
private void combobox20_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    txt_f1.Text = combobox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Dear Emad, perhaps you should consider marking his answer as answered if he helped you.

Answer (score -1):

comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();